# Adding wildfly jms subsystem with wildfly cli java api without reloading the server

Tags: wildfly, jboss-cli

So we need to provision (add the jms extension/subsystem/configurations to standalone.xml) the JMS subsystem in wildfly when starting the server if it's not already provisioned and that needs to happen automatically. We have an application written in java and we chose to provision the jms subsystem with wildfly's cli java api and that is executed when our application starts deploying. The thing is we need to provision the jms subsystem and use it in the same application.

Problem is, when we add the needed configurations in standalone.xml with wildfly's cli java api, the server requires a reload but we can't reload it because our app is already deploying, it tries to use the defined queues and fails because... Well, the subsystem is not active yet. On next server restart everything is ok but as you can guess in a production environment this is unacceptable. Is there any solution to this? I've tried adding a reload cli command in the end of the batch that creates the jms subsystem and it starts reloading the server but the deployment doesn't stop and exceptions start flying left and right.

Also the whole idea of reloading the server from the app while the app is deploying seems kinda wrong to me.

Thanks in advance.

Solution:
Well the solution in the end was an easy one, we just had to add a reload step in the batch operation that adds the jms subsystem. The problem was that we had a set of async operation that all fired off when the app was deployed so i just had to make sure none of them started until i can check for the messaging subsystem and reload wildfly if necessary. That way I'm not interrupting any async tasks forcefully.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select appropriate profile i.e full or full-ha while starting server only. If you do this there will not be need to add JMS subsystem.

If you want to go with your approach only, add dependency of queue in 
application. It will not start deploying until and unless queue is bound to server.

Comment: We want to provision the jms subsystem regardless of the profile chosen. So that's not an option. Also i have no problem with the queues, i can add them just fine while the server is running. It's the messaging subsystem that's giving me problems. I can't find a way to add it without needing to restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

we need to perform reload operation when we add new subsystem, if you dont want to perform reload operation then I will suggest you to start server in 'admin-only' mode. When we start server in 'admin-only' mode then it open only management port(9990/9999). Configure messaging subsystem through CLI command reload server instance. Hope it helps..!!

Comment: Point of the whole thing is to automate the entire process. We have multiple server instances with our app deployed on them and dont want to go through them all and start them in admin-only mode. Also, the jms subsystem is written in the standalone.xml by the app that is being deployed so we can't use admin-only or it won't deploy.